# How can I access this Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have this hash:

```
{
  "EnviarInstrucaoUnicaResponse"=>{
    "xmlns:ns1" => "http://www.moip.com.br/ws/alpha/",
    "Resposta" => {
      "ID"=>"201504171610223590000007515979",
      "Status"=>"Sucesso",
        "Token"=>"Y2F0P1R5G0D4Y1E7A196I1T0O252Z325U9H040M0E0G0Y0V7F581457957X9"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I acess the "Token" inside it?

I've tried `<%= @token[EnviarInstrucaoUnicaResponse] %>` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
Your_Hash = {
  "EnviarInstrucaoUnicaResponse"=>{
    "xmlns:ns1" => "http://www.moip.com.br/ws/alpha/",
    "Resposta" => {
      "ID"=>"201504171610223590000007515979",
      "Status"=>"Sucesso",
        "Token"=>"Y2F0P1R5G0D4Y1E7A196I1T0O252Z325U9H040M0E0G0Y0V7F581457957X9"
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
Token = Your_Hash['EnviarInstrucaoUnicaResponse']['Resposta']['Token']
```

So what you need to do is:  `<%= @token[EnviarInstrucaoUnicaResponse]['Resposta']['Token'] %>`

Answer (score 1):

Just as you would any hash:

```
@token["EnviarInstrucaoUnicaResponse"]["Reposta"]["Token"]
```

Your example isn't valid Ruby code. You need to specify keys as strings. Other languages will convert automatically for you, like Perl, but not Ruby.